# wordpress $wpdb select results to an array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

`$wp->get_results` will return an array and formats the array depends if the second parameter is specified; if not, it is default to an object, right? But my question is it possible to retrieve results then store it the an array? Like this `$arr = array(1,2,3,4,5)`? What my main concern is this.. I want to search in the array if the value is present.

Now I can't do a `in_array` if the returned results is like this.

```
$arr = array(array('1'), array('2'), array('3'), array('4'), array('5'));
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

EDITED

my `$arr` would look like this

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [code] => 8 [id] => ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [code] => 1 [id] => ) )
```

EDITED

Found a solution:

```
if (in_array(array('1'), $arr) {
  // found value
}
```

Comment: can u show ur result `$arr`? .. it will return an array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can not match directly, for matching, it you will have to do something like this :

```
$arr = array(array('1'), array('2'), array('3'), array('4'), array('5'));
foreach($arr as $newar)
{
    if (in_array('2',$newar))
    {
        echo 'hello';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really following the problem here, but assuming you want to find a specific value inside the wpdb results......

```
foreach($arr as $key => $row) {
    if($row->code == $VALUE_YOU_WANT_TO_MATCH) {
       // do something
       break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Note:**  $arr is an array of objects, its not a multidimensional array.

say for example I want to check if if `code = 1` exist in my result.

```
foreach($arr as $myarr){
  if ($myarr->code == "1"){
     echo "record was found\n";
     break;//this line makes the foreach loop end after first success.
  }
 }
```